# Multiple lanagues in hunspell / locale

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

I am finding myself more and more using French as well as English. I use hunspell (mostly on Slack and Signal) which picks languages from `locale`,

Is there a way to have my locale support both at the same time so that hunspell can correct both English and French side-by-side?

My `locale` currently read:

```
; locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

It [appears that `signal-desktop` does not support multiple languages yet…](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/1659) thus a hunspell solution would be welcome.

Comment: You can specify which language to check with `-d`, i.e. `hunspell -d en_US`.